# How to derive the solution of $F_S(x)=P \left ({|h|^{2} \le \frac { x \left ({1 + |g|^{2} \rho _{2} }\right)}{\phi \rho _{1}} }\right)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, cumulative-distribution-function, rayleigh-distribution

I came across a received signal-to-interference-plus-noise-ratio (SINR), $S$, of a wireless communication system as
\begin{align*}
 S = \frac{\phi|h|^2\rho_1}{1+|g|^{2} \rho _{2} }, \tag{1}
\end{align*}

where $\phi$ is the power allocation coefficient, $\rho_1$ is the SNR (signal-to-noise-ratio) of channel 1, $\rho_2$ is the SNR of channel 2, $h \sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$ is channel 1's gain, and $g \sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$ is channel 2's gain. Furthermore, $H= \mathbb{E}[|h|^2]$ and $G= \mathbb{E}[|g|^2]$.

The authors state that the CDF of the received SINR is

\begin{align*} F_S(x)=&P \left ({|h|^{2} \le \frac { x \left ({1 + |g|^{2} \rho _{2} }\right)}{\phi \rho _{1}} }\right), \end{align*}

where the RHS is found to be
\begin{align*} P \left ({|h|^{2} \le \frac { x \left ({1 + |g|^{2} \rho _{2} }\right)}{\phi \rho _{1}} }\right) = 1 - \frac {1}{1 + a x} e^{-\frac {x}{\phi H \rho _{1}}},\tag{2} \end{align*}

where  $a=\frac{G \rho_2}{\phi H\rho_1}$.

I understand that [$z=h_r^2+h_i^2=\frac{2}{\sigma^2} |h|^2$ is a chi squared distributed random variable with $k=2$ degrees of freedom](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78881/17800). Then, the CDF for $k=2$ is

\begin{equation}
F(z;k=2)=1-e^{-z/2}, \tag{3}
\end{equation}

which allows us to obtain the structure of (2).

However, I am unable to figure out how the $\frac {1}{1 + a x}$ in $\frac {1}{1 + a x} e^{-\frac {x}{\phi H \rho _{1}}}$ was derived.

Does the fact that $g$ is a complex random variable also affect the outcome?

Could someone help me understand how the expression in (2) was derived?

Comment: There are some strange aspects to this question.  In particular, since $\sigma^2$ determines $E[|h|^2]$ and $E[|g|^2],$ why do you introduce these latter variables?  Indeed, your result (2) is incorrect, further suggesting there are serious typographical errors in this question.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing out the issue. I have added more context in the hopes to make it clear. Regarding the correctness of result (2), I doubled checked the article, and I am afraid that it is correct in the sense that it is exactly how the authors have derived it.

Comment: Unfortunately, without strong additional assumptions, this result is false.

Comment: @whuber I believe that could be the reason why I am not able to figure this out. May I know what are these assumptions you are referring to? Or under what assumption would the result be correct?

Comment: I am beginning to suspect this can be solved, after all, assuming $G=H=2\sigma^2$ as implied by your assumptions.  One has to do the integral to compare one exponential variable $|h|^2$ to another one $|g|^2.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the inputs. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The integral turns out to be easier than it looks.**

**Let's simplify notation a little.**  By choosing suitable units for the variables, we may make $\sigma^2=1/2,$ entailing $H=G=1.$  Consequently everything depends on the values of $$\frac{1}{\phi\rho_1} = \beta \gt 0,$$ say, and $$a = \rho_2 \beta \gt 0.$$  $Y=|h|^2$ and $X=|g|^2$ are independent Exponential variables, which means that for any number $\lambda \ge 0,$

$$\Pr(X \le \lambda) = \Pr(Y \le \lambda) = 1 - e^{-\lambda}.$$

The problem is for any $\lambda\ge 0$ to compute

$$\begin{aligned}
\Pr(Y \le \beta \lambda(1 + \rho_2 X)) &= E\left[1 - e^{-( \beta\lambda(1 + \rho_2 X))}\right] \\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(1 - e^{-( \beta\lambda(1 + \rho_2 x))}\right) \,\mathrm{d}\left(1-e^{-x}\right) \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x - e^{-\lambda}\int_0^\infty e^{- \beta\lambda \rho_2 x - x}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 1 - e^{-\beta\lambda} \frac{1}{\beta\lambda\rho_1+1} \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{1 + a\lambda}e^{-\lambda/(\phi \rho_1)}.
\end{aligned}$$

In the question, "$x$" is used instead of "$\lambda:$" because $H=1,$ this result obviously agrees with the quoted formula in the question, *QED.*

Comment: Thank you very much @whuber. Appreciate it.